# If we could withstand the temperature of Sun then could we actually stand on it? Does it have a solid surface or not?

Tags: astrophysics, sun, density, stellar-physics

If the sun's temperature were lower or we could withstand it, could we actually stand still on a solid surface or would we fall through into the depth of the sun? Is the sun's surface gaseous with hydrogen and helium or solid?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Density of the Sun](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/201235/)

Comment: It's certainly related, but not quite duplicate.

Comment: An interesting side note is that the surface gravity of the Sun is about 28 times higher than the surface gravity of Earth.  Therefore, no human could stand unaided even were the surface solid.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_gravity

Comment: -1 No research effort. Whether the Sun has a solid surface is something you could find the answer to with very little effort by searching the internet.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. The linked question asks for the *density* of the Sun, and this one asks for its mechanical properties. It is perfectly possible to have material that's denser than any solid found on Earth (e.g. using sufficiently high temperatures and pressures) and which is nevertheless still a fluid. That said, though, even if you cannot stand on the Sun at any point, at some point you'll start floating (assuming some indestructible, rigid coating around you).

Answer (score 2):

I guess it depends on what you mean by surface.  First of all the sun is not solid.  Far from the center the sun is a thin, diffuse plasma.  As you get closer to the center the density increases.  The [core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun#Core) of the sun is a very dense plasma.  This is where the nuclear fusion happens.  The density is about 150 times more than water, so you would float.  You would sink slowly, so you could **stand on the core** while sinking.  The core is very dense, but it's not technically a solid.

What we usually think of as the **surface** of the sun is the [photosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun#Photosphere).  Below the photosphere the sun is so dense that any emitted light will bounce around and be reabsorbed.  It's optically thick or opaque.  The photosphere is where the sun gets thin enough that emitted visible light can escape and be seen by people outside.  If you went to the photosphere, it would not be a surface.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if we consider your scenario, which is not possible, as we approached the sun, we would encounter a medium of ever-increasing density and viscosity. We would first encounter a gaseous environment, then a liquid-like environment and then eventually we would reach the solid-like core of the sun. The sun is compacted due to the extreme pressure from the weight of the sun, which is the reason why the sun has a very dense core. So you could technically stand on the sun.

As to why the considered scenario is not possible, the sun is basically a balance between the gravitational pressure due to the mass of the sun and the radiation pressure from the nuclear fusion taking place inside the sun. If you remove either of these pressures, the sun would either explode(if the gravitational pressure is less than the radiation pressure) or it would implode(if the gravitational pressure is greater than the radiation pressure). So, if the sun was cool enough to land on it, it would not have the sufficient radiation pressure required to balance the gravitational pressure of the mass of the sun and the sun would collapse in on itself.

Comment: The solar core is not solid.  It's way denser than lead or gold, but it's a plasma with no lattice structure.