If I drop a rock on the Sun, does it fall right to the center?
Hydrostatic equilibrium is what determines the diameter of the Sun. The internal gas pressure inside the sun equalizes with the pressure from Gravity on the outside. This is what determines the size of every Star.  If I was to drop a rock on the Sun, would it fall right to the center, or would it be stopped somewhere halfway down by gas pressure pushing outwards?

Possible duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/201235/

Why wouldn't the rock vaporise long before it got anywhere near the core?

@PM2Ring I don't think that is the purpose of the question

Yeah, ok, @BioPhysicist, but the OP should clarify that in the question.

I am assuming this is a special rock, a fiducial rock--if you will (note: fiducial masses don't care about the environment other than that for which they are created--that is: fiducial masses care a bout gravity, fiducial charges don't).
With that, this is a hard question.
My naive answer is: yes and no. The yes being: yes, it will stop before the core, and then no: not because of pressure.
The no is b/c of buoyancy. The core is 150 g/cc, the rock will float long before that.
Then, that no becomes a maybe, since buoyancy can be described as a pressure gradient--but that's a detail. The fluid pressure is uniform (it's a scalar trace of a stress tensor).
Then I think about radiation pressure...it pushes just outward (so is it really a vector momentum flux?)...anyway, that is a factor.
I think the point where buoyancy overrules radiation pressure is the boundary between the radiation zone and the convection zone, so you need to post a solar model (radiation pressure and density vs. $r$ along with temperature, maybe, if you want a definitive answer).

Standard Solar Model (BP2004) https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.astro-ph/0402114 https://gist.github.com/PM2Ring/212e9a8cc73c203a93d288606ac4e466

Well,my guess is its particles, not the rock cause it would melt lol, would start interacting with the plasma. The main ingredients in rock are Fe, Si, O , Al, Ca, Na, K and Mg according to this: http://www.physicalgeography.net/fundamentals/10d.html#google_vignette
Fission is only supported until Iron but until then (and because we'll start from the outer layers which do not have "ash") the heavier elements of the rock will be stripped of their electrons (especially the ones further away which are very loosely tied to the atoms, especially when you compare them to elements like hydrogen and helium). They cannot form any chemical bonds due to the sun's heat. However, since they are now ions they will be affected not only by gravity and radiation pressure but also by the magnetic field.
If some of these nuclei do not get swept onto the surface or be ejected then they will most likely be trapped under the photosphere. I cannot find a picture right now but I think the magnetic field there is looped in layers.
Feel free to correct me.
